# Non-monotonicity under Bayesian dynamic borrowing

Tags: bayesian, estimation

Dynamic borrowing refers to the idea that information from different data sources can be shared within the Bayesian framework based on their observed similarity. Kopp-Schneider et al. (2020) mention that "in case of dynamic borrowing, the posterior probability is not necessarily a monotonically increasing function of [the number of responses]". From this, counterintuitive decision may arise - Kopp-Schneider et al. show an example for the binomial case with $n=40$ and dynamic borrowing from an external source where the rejection region is $C=\{12\} \lor \{16,...,40\}$, i.e. the null hypothesis would be rejected if 12 responses are observed but not if 13 responses would be observed.

Although this phenomenon seems logical (since less similarity means less borrowing and hence less power), the decisions arising from this are for surely not intuitive and probably undesirable in practice. I am suprised that this was the first time that I have read about these counterintuitive decisions under dynamic borrowing. Does there exist a generalization of this issue and have solutions been offered?

Kopp‐Schneider, Annette, Silvia Calderazzo, and Manuel Wiesenfarth. "Power gains by using external information in clinical trials are typically not possible when requiring strict type I error control." Biometrical Journal 62.2 (2020): 361-374.

Comment: Note that when historical information is relevant, type I assertion probability $\alpha$ has no meaning.  So I'm not sure why the Kopp-Schneider paper was needed.  Most researchers using dynamical borrowing are considering the other studies to be exchangeable with the current study.  But I see in many of these cases that the studies are not exchangeable, so the use of hierarchical models to achieve the borrowing is suspect to me.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Thank you a lot for your considered answer, Professor Harrell. Do I understand your argument correctly that you would refrain from hierarchical models if studies are only partly exchangeable? Is there any benefit in applying dynamic borrowing (compared to full borrowing) if studies are assumed to be fully exchangeable?

Comment: Primarily, yes.  In general I like to use a mixture of skeptical prior with the posterior from other data.  Mixing proportion is the prior probability of applicability of the previous results.

Comment: @FrankHarrell I appreciate this insight. Such mixture priors should indeed always avoid the above described counterintuitive decisions. In the Kopp-Schneider paper, this was also mentioned. But this assumes that the external information is historical - what kind of borrowing would you use for parallel subgroups within a trial (basket/umbrella/platform) ?

Comment: Very good question.  First of all make sure the subgroups are legitimate subgroups.  Many studies create invalid subgroups by binning a continuous variable.  To your question, borrowing across the covariate space is achieved by having skeptical priors (centered at zero effects) on interaction terms. This works until you have a very number of mutually exclusive groups at which point a hierarchical model is preferred.

Comment: @FrankHarrell this is a valuable answer. So in situations, where we have adults and children, it might sometimes make sense to use a continuous covariate to represent "physiological age", e.g. built from age and body weight, and use a sceptical prior on the interaction term. I further conclude that one potential solution to the problem of non-monotonicity is to use robust priors instead of dynamic borrowing, although I am not sure yet whether that is actually true in general.

Comment: The use of an interaction between age and treatment, with discounting of the interaction term through a prior, is a good one in the case where you have patient-level data on all patients.  In most cases the patient-level data from past studies is not readily available (although it should have been).